# Conditional promise in JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to reduce the need for multiple functions, especially as many have a `promise` that is doing the same thing. However, I am looking to add a condition based on `props` from a parent.

For example I have a function

```
example
  .doSomething()
  .then(something => {
    example.createSomething(something)
  });
```

But how can I add a condition that changes `.doSomething()` from `props` of `somethingElse` to `.doSomethingElse()`?

Therefore, if `somethingElse === true` the function will be

```
example
  .doSomethingElse()
  .then(something => {
    example.createSomething(something)
  });
```

Comment: so why not `if (somethingElse) example.doSomethingElse...) else example.doSomething`?

Comment: OP wants to branch the condition but the result eventually converge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am writing this in my phone don't blame me, might tidy up later.

```js
Promise.resolve(somethingElse ? example.doSomethingElse() : example.doSomething())
    .then(...
```

if you think writing twice `example` is tedious

```js
Promise.resolve(example[somethingElse ? "doSomethingElse" : "doSomething"]())
    .then(...
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

By @Phil

if both(all) functions return a `Promise`
can simply do

```js
example[somethingElse ? "doSomethingElse" : "doSomething"]().then(...
```

Note that it means `Promise.resolve` above can even handle non-Promise return value

Comment: this is nothing related to react though, it's just vanilla js feature (someone include MDN Promise's link for me?)

Comment: Assuming both `doSomething()` and `doSomethingElse()` return a promise, there's absolutely no need to wrap them in another one with `Promise.resolve()`. You could use your second example without `Promise.resolve()` to the exact same effect

Comment: `Promise.resolve` was the secret here. I have many functions returning the same promise and instead sorted my conditional returns using `let examples` and then assigning each as `if (somethingElse) { examples = 'doSomethingElse' }`. Then using `Promise.resolve` I followed the second example above as  `(example[examples]()).then`. A great help, thanks.

Comment: @Phil You are right, just in case `doSomething()` return a simple `thenable` object instead of a `Promise`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Promise.all method

```js
let cleaRoom = function(){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            resolve('room is cleaed')
        })
    }
    let removeGarbage = function(message){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            resolve(message + ' garbage is removed')
        })
    }
    let wonIcecream = function(message){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            resolve(message + ' won the icecream');
        })
    }
Promise.all([cleaRoom(),removeGarbage(),wonIcecream()]).then(function(){
    console.log('finished all');
})
```